# How can 'Group By' on a ultrawingrid column?

Tags: c#, infragistics

On the control appears a feature saying 'Drag a column header to gorup by that column'. Can i do that programmatically. Are there any properties or do I need to embed SQL statements?

Thanks,
Sun

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to add the column to the SortedColumns collection in the band:

```
    private void SwitchGroupByFor(string key) //key stands for the ultragridcolumn key
    {
        var band = grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0];
        var sortedColumns = band.SortedColumns;

        sortedColumns.Add(key, false, true); //last flag indicates is a group by column
    }
```

hth

Comment: key meaning? Is the actual column grid i.e. "CustomerId"?

Comment: Hi sunscreen, yes is the key of the UltraGridColumn, I think there is an override that takes the column too if you already have that

Comment: Cool I ll look at it when the server is on (AGAIN!) ;) The definition of band (var band) and sortedColumns does not compile? var is not known type for the compiler (using C@ 2). Ant alternatives?

Comment: just use it like this: grid.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].SortedColumns.Add(key, false, true)
The 'var' works from c# 3.0 and is a replacement for the specific type

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here :
http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/p/2418/15231.aspx#15231
and here :
http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/t/5928.aspx

These lines are the one that do the magic :
`grid1.DisplayLayout.ViewType = ViewType.OutlookGroupBy;
    grid1.Rows.Band.Columns[0].IsGroupByColumn = true;
    grid1.Rows.Band.Expandable = Expandable.Yes;`

Comment: This has changed : the IsGroupByColumn property is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd also note that if you want to clear the group by here is how:
myGrid.Rows.Band.SortedColumns.Clear()